# How to display XML data(list) in HTML(CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want build a website that have two "table" to display two lists of data that stored in XML.
Category and items(think todo list. one category has more then one item)

I'm not sure how to display the list of data. What kind specific technique should I use? Can I only use HTML and CSS to achieve this(My friend said I have to use javascript).

Comment: Ajax exchanging data with a server, and updating parts of a web page. I mean if I have a list of data. How do I display them?

Comment: It will be a lot easier if you convert the XML to JSON object, then render. https://github.com/buglabs/node-xml2json. If you can convert the XML to JSON format in the server-side before returning to client, it will probably be an easier process.

Answer (score 1):

U need to use AJAX for that purpose.
AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript XML...
This will help you to get your XML data loaded on Web Pages

Comment: Thanks. It automatic displays the data on the web page or I need extra display method?

Comment: If you know jquery then it is lot more easier to add XML data to your web page with the help of AJAX. AJAX can be used with jquery to do that and very efficient too. This link can help you. http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/